# Async request with redux-saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm learning redux-saga, so far I created basic project with working local app state (plus and minus buttons) but there is a problem with async part.

Basically redux is stuck during request action.

Link do codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-dirac-vxy1s

> Here is part of code that is not working as @Clarity suggested:

**actions.js**

```
export const CLICKER_GET_POST_REQUEST = "CLICKER_GET_POST_REQUEST";
export const CLICKER_GET_POST_SUCCESS = "CLICKER_GET_POST_SUCCESS";
export const CLICKER_GET_POST_FAILED = "CLICKER_GET_POST_FAILED";

export const clickerGetPostRequest = () => ({
  type: CLICKER_GET_POST_REQUEST
});

export const clickerGetPostSuccess = payload => ({
  type: CLICKER_GET_POST_SUCCESS,
  payload
});

export const clickerGetPostFailed = payload => ({
  type: CLICKER_GET_POST_FAILED,
  payload
});
```

**reducer.js**

```
const initialState = {
  post: {},
  isLoading: false,
  isError: false
};

export default function ClickerReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CLICKER_GET_POST_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true
      };
    case CLICKER_GET_POST_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        post: action.payload
      };
    case CLICKER_GET_POST_FAILED:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        isError: true
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**saga.js**

```
export default function*() {
  yield [
    takeEvery(CLICKER_GET_POST_REQUEST, fetchPost)
  ];
}

function* fetchPost() {
  try {
    const response = yield call(
      fetch,
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"
    );
    const data = yield response.json();
    yield put(clickerGetPostSuccess(data));
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(clickerGetPostFailed());
  }
}
```

> At the end 'clickerGetPostRequest' is executed but
>   'clickerGetPostSuccess' nor 'clickerGetPostFailed' ever runs.

Comment: Instead of linking to sandbox, create a minimal reproducible example here.

Comment: I updated post, hope this is enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're yielding an array, you need to wrap the array in `all`:

```
import { all } from "redux-saga/effects";

export default function*() {
  yield all([
    takeEvery(CLICKER_GET_POST_REQUEST, fetchPost)
  ]);
}
```

The same applies to the array of sagas in your `rootSaga.js`.

Comment: No problem. Remember to also accept the answer if it solved your issue.